# netsh http add urlacl work like a local DNS?

Tags: http, dns, iis-express, netsh

I'm using `netsh http add urlacl url=http://devsite1:80/ user=everyone` as mentioned at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx to work with 80 and 443 SSL port, but `web browser can't bind my http://devsite1 local address` and them, nothing work.

Should be really have set line as `127.0.0.1 devsite1` at hosts file in Windows drive etc folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this link above he said:

> My machine is called HANSELMAN-W500, so I'll use that name. **You could update your hosts    file and use a friendly name**. To start, use your computer name. if you don't know the name of your computer, you're silly. Go to the command prompt and type "HOSTNAME" to find out.

Comment: But, so he tell us `First, we need to tell HTTP.SYS at the kernel level that it's OK to let everyone talk to this URL by making an "Url Reservation."` **What he want to told with let everyone talk to this URL?** Local devices at network? I guess no, because there not DNS record for that. So what it is?